# LXDE panel move right-hand Info-apps to right

Tags: debian, lxde

I can't find out how to move the Information-apps (Battery, calendar, Volume etc.) to the right side of the panel. These accidentally moved automatically to the center of the panel. Any Ideas? Below a picture of my screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Files defining the layout of panels are in ~/.config/lxpanel//panels. Each file in the directory defines a panel. On startup, all panels defined in those files are loaded. The default config file looks like given below. I have just pasted the part which I guess you will need to edit.

```
>     # Global section: defines appearance and behavior of this panel.      
>     Global 
>     {
>     edge=bottom    # The edge this panel attaches to
>     allign=left    # alignment: left/center/right
>     margin=0       # margin: margin to the edge of the whole screen
>     widthtype=percent   # percent/pixel
>     width=100      # width of the panel: The unit used here is according to widthtype.
>     height=26      # height of the panel
>     transparent=0  # use (pseudo-)transparent background: on=1, off=0
>     tintcolor=#000000  # color blended with the backgroud when transparency is used.
>     alpha=0    # alpha value used to blend tintcolor with background.
>     setdocktype=1   # ask the window manager to treat the panel as a dock.
>     setpartialstrut=1  # ask the window manager to reserve the space for the panel and not to cover it with maximized windows
>     usefontcolor=1   # use customize colors for the text instead of that defined in system theme.
>     fontcolor=#ffffff   # color of text on the panel (Currently this is only supported by clock applet)
>     background=1    # use customize image to draw the background of the panel. (cannot be used with transparent)
>     backgroundfile=/usr/share/lxpanel/images/background.png  # The image file used. 
>     }
```

So u will need to edit the `allign` variable.

Comment: I have a `panel` file in `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels` directory, but there my `align` is already set to `right`!